# iOS UIAlertController bold button changed in 8.3

Tags: ios, button, uialertcontroller

UIAlertController with two buttons with styles set:

```
UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel
UIAlertActionStyle.Default
```

in iOS 8.2, the Cancel button is non-bold and Default is bold.
In iOS 8.3 they have switched round

You can see it Apple's own apps e.g., Settings > Mail > Add Account > iCloud > enter invalid data, then it shows like this on 8.3:

Unsupported Apple ID

Learn More (bold)
OK (non-bold)

whereas it was the other way round for 8.2.

Any workaround to make it like 8.2 again. Why has it changed?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

From iOS 9 you can set the `preferredAction` value to the action which you want the button title to be bold.

```
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(OKAction)
    alert.preferredAction = OKAction
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true) {}
```

The OK button which is on the right will be in bold font.

Comment: Note that this only works with `UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert` (not action sheets).

Answer (score 16):

This is an intentional change to the SDK. I have just had a response from Apple to [this radar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5490788398006272) on the issue, stating that:

> This is an intentional change - the cancel button is to be bolded in alerts.

I can't find anything in the various change logs mentioning this, unfortunately.

So, we'll need to make changes to our apps in places to make some things make sense.

Answer (score 12):

Since iOS 9, `UIAlertController` has a property called [`preferredAction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller/1620102-preferredaction). `preferredAction` has the following declaration:

```
var preferredAction: UIAlertAction? { get set }
```

> The preferred action for the user to take from an alert. [...] The preferred action is relevant for the `UIAlertController.Style.alert` style only; it is not used by action sheets. When you specify a preferred action, the alert controller highlights the text of that action to give it emphasis. (If the alert also contains a cancel button, the preferred action receives the highlighting instead of the cancel button.) [...] The default value of this property is `nil`.

---

The Swift 5 / iOS 12 sample code below shows how to display a `UIAlertController` that will highlight the text of a specified `UIAlertAction` using `preferredAction`:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
    print("Hello")
})

alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
alertController.addAction(okAction)
alertController.preferredAction = okAction

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just checked in iOS 8.2: a **first** added button is non-bold and a **second** added button is bold. With this code a cancel button will be bold:

```
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:nil]];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                  handler:nil]];
```

And with this code a default button will be bold:

```
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                  handler:nil]];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:nil]];
```

I can't check in iOS 8.3 now but this behavior can be a reason.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried it but it makes no difference in 8.3. I think it must be an Apple bug as it looks wrong in their alerts. Eg the Push Notifications alert now has **Don't Allow** (bold) OK (non bold) which is surely not what anyone wants...

Comment: It must be a bug for system alerts, but you can add your buttons (actions) in the right sequence for iOS 8.2 (8.3?) or set a right style for action if the action's style is a reason of a bold style.

Comment: Agreed. This is very odd. Order doesn't make any difference, why is no the bold type?

Comment: I would assume no change is by default "correct" - and therefore bold. I assume Apple wants to nudge users to be more critical to blindly allowing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Some words about objective-c and preferredAction for alertActions. If you use preferredAction you BOUTH alertAction must set as style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault. If some one will be set as style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel, preferredAction will be ignored

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"All you base"
                                                                         message:@"Are belong to us!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* alertActionShowYes = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"YES!" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    NSLog(@"I serve for my emperor!");
}];

UIAlertAction* alertActionNo = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"NO!" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    NSLog(@"NOOOO it's not true!!");
}];

[alertController addAction:alertActionShowYes];
[alertController addAction:alertActionNo];

alertController.preferredAction = alertActionShowYes;
[alertController setPreferredAction:alertActionShowYes];
    
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```