# UIalertcontroller sequence of buttons

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I would like to change the sequence of alert action button, as per code I tried all possibility but it is not allowed me to change the sequence.

As per HIG, cancel is on right hand side
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1

See my code here

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"My alert message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                   [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                               }];

UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {

                                    [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                }];


[alertController addAction:yesButton];
[alertController addAction:noButton];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

this will give me following result. I want to change Cancel `button` on right hand and OK `button` on left hand side.

[image]

I appreciate for your time.

Comment: The cancel button should only be on the right if the other option is a destructive action, in which case you should use `UIAlertActionStyleDestructive` for that action.  Having it on the left is the correct behavior when the right side is `UIAlertActionStyleDefault`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the action style for cancel button type to `UIAlertActionStyleDefault` instead of `UIAlertActionStyleCancel`

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"My alert message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                            handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                            {

                                [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                            }];

UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                           {
                               [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                           }];

[alertController addAction:yesButton];
[alertController addAction:noButton];


[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And now you can change the order of the buttons by simply changing the positions of

```
 [alertController addAction:yesButton]; //If you yesButton to appear first (left)
 [alertController addAction:noButton];
```

The `UIAlertActions` are flexible enough to reorder. They are not fixed .

Comment: its works, thanks but I was wondering why style are (UIAlertActionStyleDefault) same for both alert actions? I was trying UIAlertActionStyleDefault and second one UIAlertActionStyleCance l!!!

Comment: The style Cancel will alwyas be in the left side! The HIG doesn't tell you that cancel button should always be on left. It is upto user convinience.

Comment: I agreed, one more point I observe, iOs 8.1 will display bold cancel when iOS 9.2 is normal font cancel button.  But in ios 9, UIAlertActionStyleCance will always be in bold letter.

Comment: you can always bold the uialertAction using the preferredAction method.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590534/ios-uialertcontroller-bold-button-changed-in-8-3

Answer (score 18):

People, it's a little old thread but if you want to have the bold font in the right button, you just need to set that action as '.preferredAction' property for the alert object. Hope this can help. I've just proved it on swift 3 / iOS10 and it works just fine.